# Utilizando hover para ampliar icone ao passar o mouse por cima com CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Olá, estou tentando deixar a minha listagem animada, passando o mouse por cima das opções (Visualizar, Editar e Excluir) e quero que o icon fique maior, só para ter uma melhor visualização, estou com um código, porém, não está tendo resultados...

**CSS utilizado:**

```
 .zoom{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

**Estrutura no PHP:**

```
      <td>
           <div class='zoom'>
           <div class='table-data-feature'>

           <a href='#' title='Visualizar' style='color:black'>
           <i class='fas fa-file-pdf' style='margin: 0 8px;'></i>
           </a>

           <a href='#' title='Editar' style='color:black'>
           <i class='zmdi zmdi-edit' style='margin: 0 8px'></i>
           </a>

           <a href='#' title='Excluir' style='color:black'>
           <i class='fas fa-power-off' style='margin: 0 8px'></i>
           </a>

           </div>
           </div>
     </td>
```

> Acentos simples, pois está dentro de um `echo`...
>
> Eu consegui fazer com imagens, porém, não dentro de um `while`...

Answer (score 2):

Para acionar o evento passar o mouse em cima(hover) você deve utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
{seletor}:hover {
    código css
}
```

No seu caso como você quer aumentar os itens, não a lista inteira, ficaria assim:

```
 .zoom a:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```